# How to SUM numbers from a plain jsonb array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, timescaledb

I'm facing issues with a jsonb ARRAY column in PostgreSQL.
I need to sum this column for each row.

[image: Sample values for the jsonb column]

Expected Result:

| index | sum(snx_wavelenghts) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 223123 |
| 2 | 223123 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this ...

... with a subquery, then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT index, sum(nr) AS wavelength_sum
FROM  (
   SELECT index, jsonb_array_elements(snx_wavelengths)::numeric AS nr 
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional?
```

... with an aggregate in a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT index
    , (SELECT sum(nr::numeric) FROM jsonb_array_elements(snx_wavelengths) nr) AS wavelength_sum
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional?
```

... or with an aggregate in a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT t.index, js.wavelength_sum
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sum(nr::numeric) AS wavelength_sum
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.snx_wavelengths) nr 
   ) js ON true
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional?
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HPJCJeOS)

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Your screenshot shows fractional digits. Cast to the type `numeric` to get *exact* results. A floating point type like `real` or `float` can introduce rounding errors.

Comment: Wow, It really works, I spent a lot of time on that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to extract the jsonb array contents from the jsonb array using `jsonb_array_elements` function before summing them. Here’s an example

```
SELECT SUM(w::float) AS wavelength_sum
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(snx_wavelengths) AS w 
  FROM my_table
);
```

This should work if I remember correctly (remember to update `my_table` to your table name). More info here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html