# How to avoid duplicated rows when joining multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate

I am trying to `SELECT` the data from the `education` and `experience` tables. Both have two entries for the given `candidate_id`. When I try using `GROUP BY` and `json_agg`, I get four rows in the aggregated JSON values. What am I doing wrong? I want *two* education objects and two experience objects in their respective arrays.

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(education) as education,
    json_agg(experience) as experience
FROM application
LEFT JOIN candidate ON application.candidate_id = candidate.id
LEFT JOIN education ON candidate.id = education.candidate_id
LEFT JOIN experience ON candidate.id = experience.candidate_id
WHERE application.candidate_id = 2
GROUP BY education.candidate_id, experience.candidate_id;
```

Result:

```
education
[{"id":3,"candidate_id":2,"school":"school1 candidate2","qualification":"qualification1 candidate2","dates":"dates1 candidate2","note":null}, 
 {"id":3,"candidate_id":2,"school":"school1 candidate2","qualification":"qualification1 candidate2","dates":"dates1 candidate2","note":null}, 
 {"id":4,"candidate_id":2,"school":"school2 candidate2","qualification":"qualification2 candidate2","dates":"dates2 candidate2","note":null}, 
 {"id":4,"candidate_id":2,"school":"school2 candidate2","qualification":"qualification2 candidate2","dates":"dates2 candidate2","note":null}]

experience
[{"id":3,"candidate_id":2,"employer":"emploer1 candidate2","title":"title1 candidate2","dates":"dates1 candidate2","job_duties":"duties1 candidate2"}, 
 {"id":4,"candidate_id":2,"employer":"emploer2 candidate2","title":"title2 candidate2","dates":"dates2 candidate2","job_duties":"duties2 candidate2"}, 
 {"id":3,"candidate_id":2,"employer":"emploer1 candidate2","title":"title1 candidate2","dates":"dates1 candidate2","job_duties":"duties1 candidate2"}, 
 {"id":4,"candidate_id":2,"employer":"emploer2 candidate2","title":"title2 candidate2","dates":"dates2 candidate2","job_duties":"duties2 candidate2"}]
```

I tried multiple variants of this query ...

Comment: You need to aggregate them in separate subqueries, then combine (once you have one-row per application.id from the subqueries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple joins that do not (also) associate rows among the joined table rows effectively act like `CROSS JOIN` by proxy, multiplying rows. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

Aggregate *before* joining (so that only a single row per parent row remains, hence no duplication). Or use lowly correlated subqueries for this simple case. Well, not even *correlated* for just your single `candidate_id`, rather plain suquery expressions in the `SELECT` list:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT json_agg(e.*)
        FROM   education e
        WHERE  e.candidate_id = 2)  AS education
     , (SELECT json_agg(e.*)
        FROM   experience e
        WHERE  e.candidate_id = 2)  AS experience
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM application a WHERE a.candidate_id = 2);
```

I removed the table `candidate` from your query, which was dead freight (unless you must verify that a related row exists in that table), but might additionally multiply rows in the same way.

And the table `application` only needs to be checked for the existence of any qualifying rows.

You might alternatively use (`LATERAL`) subqueries for more complex cases. (I suspect you over-simplified.) See:

- [How to SUM numbers from a plain jsonb array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74765081/how-to-sum-numbers-from-a-plain-jsonb-array/74766518#74766518)